# Swift: Two timer in different functions

Tags: swift, timer, gyroscope

i fetch the gyroscope data of the phone in the following func:

```
    // Sensor data from the phone
    func startGyros() {
        if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
            self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.3
            self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

            // Configure a timer to fetch the accelerometer data.
            let timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (0.3),
                              repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                                // Get the gyro data, transfer data to angle
                                if let data = self.motion.deviceMotion {
                                    let x = data.gravity.x * 180 / Double.pi
                                    let y = data.gravity.y * 180 / Double.pi
                                    let z = data.gravity.z * 180 / Double.pi

                                    // Linke Hand Zuordnung Position -> Variable
                                    if x <= 30 && x >= 20 && y <= -5 && y >= -10 {
                                        self.varLinkeHandHandgelenk = 1
                                    }
})

            // Add the timer to the current run loop.
            RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        }
    }
```

i set the `varLinkeHandHandgelenk = 1` to display a view.
What I now want to do is to count with a timer the seconds, how long I stay at one position and changing the .alpha to different values with the following code:

```
func setupTimerIfPositionIsReach() {
        if varLinkeHandHandgelenk == 1 {
          self.linkeHandHandgelenkTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(startLinkeHandHandHandgelenkTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            if counterLinkeHandHandgelenk == 1 {
                linkeHandHandgelenk.isHidden = false
                linkeHandHandgelenk.alpha = 0.7
            } else if counterLinkeHandHandgelenk == 2 {
                linkeHandHandgelenk.isHidden = false
                linkeHandHandgelenk.alpha = 0.8
            } else if counterLinkeHandHandgelenk == 3 {
                linkeHandHandgelenk.isHidden = false
                linkeHandHandgelenk.alpha = 0.9
            }
            else if counterLinkeHandHandgelenk == 4 {
                linkeHandHandgelenk.isHidden = false
                linkeHandHandgelenk.alpha = 1.0
            }
            print(1)
        } else {
            self.linkeHandHandgelenkTimer?.invalidate()
            self.linkeHandHandgelenkTimer = nil
        }
    }

    @objc func startLinkeHandHandHandgelenkTimer() {
        counterLinkeHandHandgelenk += 1
        print("This is a second ", counterLinkeHandHandgelenk)

    }
```

The problem is the second timer dont't run after I get the var `varLinkeHandHandgelenk = 1`.

I call `startGyros()` and `setupTimerIfPositionIsReach()` in viewDidLoad.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Even if you get it running, which it should, you won't get `counterLinkeHandHandgelenk` evaluated. You should put those if clause in `startLinkeHandHandHandgelenkTimer`.

Comment: thank you! Could be the problem the loop in `startGyros´? Normally it should work I now. Thanks for your help!